# Bind Individual DataGrid Cells to Individual Array Elements

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

As it says in the title, I am trying to bind individual column cells to individual elements in my load array, but I'm not sure how to perform the binding.

VM implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

```
foreach( Load L in VM.GetLoads()) //returns an ienumerable array of loads
{
    LoadGrid2.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn());
    LoadGrid2.Columns[L.Index].Binding = VM.Loads[L.Index]; // this doens't work but illustrates what I am trying to get done
}
```

[edit] Is there any chance that changing VM to implement IDynamicMetaObjectProvider could help?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//ff800651.aspx

[edit] Now I am thinking that perhaps I shoud be using a xaml defined UserControl?

Comment: You can't bind *column cells*, you can only bind *columns* ... can you provide a bit more context of what you're trying to do?  (What is `Load`, what should the grid look like?)

Comment: I am trying to create a dynamic (programatically added) list of horizontally alligned textboxes which are databound to an array.  This would be equivalent to a datagrid collumn where you can dynamically add vertically alligned textboxes.  The only real difference is that I need the elements to be aranged horrizontally.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, bind it to the array, and then put an `ItemsControl` in the template to display the text boxes?